# Getting a Web Accessible Directory in Spring-MVC/Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Simple problem, I need to write a sitemap to my web root directory so that it is accessible as so:

http://mysite.com/sitemap.xml

I want the code to look like:

```
File f = new File( someMethodToGetWebRootDirectory() );
```

But I don't know what should be in that method

Comment: The parent directory of your WEB-INF directory is the root directory. Doesn't `new File("sitemap.xml")` get you the right path?

Comment: nope, that was the first thing I tried, it puts it in some config folder in my application server, that's another thing, this needs to be consistent across web-servers

Answer (score 0):

Will something along the lines of:

```
File classesDir = new File(YourServlet.class.getProtectionDomain()
    .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().replaceAll('/', File.separator));
File rootDir = classesDir.getParentFile().getParentFile();
```

work?

Comment: There might not be a solution to this that works across application servers. One can imagine a server which never expands a war file onto disk.